# requests.get throws UnicodeEncodeError in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am having trouble with the requests library in Python 3.

This is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.contrataciones.gov.py/images/opendata/planificaciones/2016.csv'
r = requests.get(url)
reader = csv.DictReader(r.content.splitlines())
```

It works totally fine when I run the script with Python 2, but with Python 3 I get a failure at the `requests.get(url)` line:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 359: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong? I know how to decode the content and so on, but I am thrown by getting the error directly from requests.

UPDATE: Full traceback - looks like it might be something to do with pickle?

```
  File "fetch.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "fetch.py", line 115, in main
    id_list = fetchList(options.year)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ratelimit/__init__.py", line 21, in func_wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kargs)
  File "fetch.py", line 89, in fetchList
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 126, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 97, in send
    response, timestamp = self.cache.get_response_and_time(cache_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py", line 70, in get_response_and_time
    if key not in self.responses:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 666, in __contains__
    self[key]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py", line 163, in __getitem__
    return pickle.loads(bytes(super(DbPickleDict, self).__getitem__(key)))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 359: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Btw. word of caution, Python 2.x built-in `csv` module doesn't support unicode, use [`unicodecsv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) as a drop-in replacement if the CSV is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Hm - I wonder if it's because I ran it first in Python 2, then in Python 3, and pickle has got confused?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, implicit str type is ASCII. But in Python 3.x implicit str type is Unicode.

```
print(type('default string '))
print(type(b'string with b '))

'''
Output in Python 2.x (Bytes is same as str)
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>

Output in Python 3.x (Bytes and str are different)
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
'''
```

Your error at line 89: `r = requests.get(url)`
in python 3.x Bytes and str are different. so python 3.x convert Bytes into default encoding UTF-8, you need to decode it back to previous value.

This might fix your problem, give it a try
Add these lines before line 89:

```
try:
    url = url.decode("utf-8")
except UnicodeEncodeError: 
    pass
```

Here is there explanation, decode function only works for encoded string

```
>>> s = "x,jnvjlf"
>>> d = s.encode("utf-8")
>>> d
b'x,jnvjlf'
>>> e = s.decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
>>> e = d.decode("utf-8")
>>> e
'x,jnvjlf'
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference here?

Comment: I had to add `from importlib import reload` to target Python 3, and then I get `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`.

Comment: if u are using pickle then try to load ur data like this `pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')` and if possible show some more code

Answer (score -1):

You have to decode your url before requesting.

Try this:

```
newurl = url.decode("utf-8")
r = requests.get(newurl)
```

Comment: That was a really stupid but fatal mistake, I am sorry about that, the string "url" was supposed to be decoded. Apologies!

Comment: I just get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.